# --strictNullCheck using msbuild

Tags: typescript, msbuild

Is there a way to use strict null checks when compiling with msbuild?

From the documentation I get that the compiler options is --strictNullChecks,
but on the msbuild config page, they show some mappings but there is no entry for this one.

Is there a way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use it?

MsBuild supports picking up tsconfig.json. Just use that

Comment: Thanks, Good idea! I'm surprised that you can use flags on the .csproj and I was using it because it was simpler, but many flags are not supported....